# No phonegap folder added to sencha touch project

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I have download the sencha touch 3.2 and the Sencha CMD

I run this command to generate an sencha touch project

```
sencha generate app myapp myapp
```

then i run this command to add phonegap to sencha touch project

```
sencha phonegap init com.mycompany.myapp myapp
```

I do it like this: http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/20/SenchaPhoneGap/

But when i apply the "sencha phonegap init com.mycompany.myapp myapp", the CMD window only show this text "Sencha Cmd v5.0.0.160".

When i open the myapp folder ( generated from " sencha generate app myapp myapp" command ). I don't see any new file/folder.

Isn't the "sencha phonegap init com.mycompany.myapp myapp" not work ?

p/s: When i CD to the sencha touch project and type "sencha phonegap init com.mycompany.myapp myapp" . It raise this error .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try use -d option to see more detail first

```
sencha -d phonegap init com.mycompany.myapp myapp
```